# OpenGL ES 2.0: Commands required just before glDrawElements with VBO

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

I've setup a Vertex Buffer Object (VBO) with vertex and index data. I've also created a GLprogram to use custom shaders, so I call `glUseProgram` within my code.

My vertex data changes every frame, so I've supplied `GL_STREAM_DRAW` to my two `glBufferData` calls (one for vertex data, one for indices).

I use `glBufferSubData` to modify regions of my vertex data when they change. At each frame I want to draw from the first vertex to the Nth, with N being a changing value.

My question is: **which commands must I call *every time* that I call `glDrawElements`?** Ideally I'd like to simply call `glDrawElements` on its own in each frame, for performance reasons.

I'm poring over the book "OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide" but nowhere does it tell me which commands I must use every time I draw, and which I need to call only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glDrawElements` submits geometry. If you're using VBOs then it uses entries in the currently bound `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` to index entries in the relevant portions of the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` or buffers bound for each attribute.

If you don't change any other bindings then is no need to repeat any call other than `glDrawElements`. If, where you currently call `glDrawElements` you copy and paste that line to appear twice, all your geometry will be drawn twice as many times as before.